# Determining which encryption algorithm was used to encrypt a particular drive?

Tags: encryption, veracrypt

Is there a way to determine which encryption algorithm (AES, Serpent, etc) was used on a particular VeraCrypt drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on what information you have available. If you have the encryption key, you can select the volume name in the VeraCrypt dialog and click the *Volume Properties* button. This will tell you information about the volume, such as the size, mode, and encryption algorithm. If you do not have the key and only the opaque, encrypted data, then there is no way to detect the encryption algorithm in use. VeraCrypt encrypts the header, which includes metadata such as the algorithm. The way it is able to decrypt without knowing the encryption algorithm beforehand is by trying each possible algorithm with the provided key. If the header decrypts correctly, then it uses that algorithm. If none of the algorithms work, then it assumes you entered an incorrect key and tells you such.